# Need advice for my vhdl code

Tags: vhdl

I am working on my college project a digital clock on altera board. the problem i am facing is my hours goes to 29 instead of 24! I am using integer type for my hours right digit ranging 0 to 9; i got if statement that when my hours left digit is 2 and hours right digit is 3 i want my second, minutes and hours 00:00:00.. But its not implementing why? Need some advice... Thanks
here is my code :

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
entity master is 

 port( 
 clk : in std_logic;
 hrs_lft : out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0 );
 hrs_rght : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0 );
 min_lft : out std_logic_vector(2 downto 0 );
 min_rght : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0 );
 second_lft: out std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
 second_rght : out std_logic_vector( 3 downto 0)
 );
 end master;


 architecture bhv of master is
 signal second_lft_int : integer range 0 to 5;
 signal second_rght_int : integer range 0 to 9;
 signal min_lft_int : integer range 0 to 5;
 signal min_rght_int : integer range 0 to 9;
 signal hrs_lft_int : integer range 0 to 2;
 signal hrs_rght_int : integer range 0 to 9;
 begin 
 process(clk)
 begin 
 if (rising_edge(clk)) then
 second_rght_int <= second_rght_int + 1;
 if second_rght_int = 9 then 

 second_lft_int <= second_lft_int + 1;
 second_rght_int <= 0; 
   if second_lft_int  = 5 then 
       second_lft_int <= 0;   

        min_rght_int <= min_rght_int + 1;

            if min_rght_int = 9 then
              min_lft_int <= min_lft_int + 1;
              min_rght_int <= 0;
          if min_rght_int = 5 then
                  hrs_rght_int <= hrs_rght_int + 1;
                    min_rght_int <= 0;
               if  hrs_rght_int = 9 then
                  hrs_lft_int <= hrs_lft_int + 1;
                  if (hrs_rght_int = 3 and hrs_lft_int = 2) then
                  hrs_lft_int <= 0;
                  hrs_rght_int <= 0;
              min_lft_int <= 0;
              min_rght_int <= 0;  
     second_rght_int <= 0;
     second_lft_int <= 0;
     end if ;
     end if;
     end if;
     end if;
     end if;
     end if;
     end if;
     end process;
     second_rght<=                          std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(second_rght_int,second_rght'length));
    second_lft<=std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(second_lft_int,second_lft'length));
    min_rght<= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(min_rght_int,min_rght 'length));
    min_lft <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(min_lft_int,min_lft'length));
    hrs_rght<= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(hrs_rght_int,hrs_rght 'length));
    hrs_lft <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(hrs_lft_int,hrs_lft'length));
end bhv;
```

Comment: Dumb question....but if your hrs_rght_int is integer range 0 to 4...then how's 18:00 o'clock supposed to happen?

edit: I mean your copy/paste code says so although your description states othewise.

Comment: Also, your code has no resets, so statements like "if second_lft_int  = 5" take a bold assumption that the value is always 0..5. But in reality the value for 3bit vector could easily be something like 6. This is the first reason for resets -> to have a known state for start.

Comment: @JarnoNurminen This code seems to have a lot synchronous resets  (assignments of zeros). And this also favorited here.

Comment: Please indent your code properly. As it is currently written, the nesting of `if` statements is hard to follow and likely to be the error. Please also show your testbench.

Comment: @Martin, I am sorry, but I fail to see any resets in the code? There are some assignments to zero but they do not fill the definition of reset. If for example **second_rght_int** is not 9, there are no assignments done for the other signals. But the indentation is horrible thus making the code unreadable.

Comment: @JarnoNurminen Maybe we have a different meaning of "reset".  The digits are initialized to zero because of the integer sub-range. And at least some digits are reset to zero, when the highest number has been reached.

Answer (score 0):

You process didn't look right, so I wrote it de novo:

```
    process (clk)
    begin 
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if second_rght_int = 9 then
                second_rght_int <= 0;
                if second_lft_int = 5 then
                    second_lft_int <= 0;
                    if min_rght_int = 9 then
                        min_rght_int <= 0;
                        if  min_lft_int = 5 then
                             min_lft_int <= 0;
                            if (hrs_lft_int = 2 and hrs_rght_int = 4)
                                             or hrs_rght_int = 9 then
                                hrs_rght_int <= 0;
                                    if hrs_lft_int = 2 then
                                        hrs_lft_int <= 0;
                                    else
                                        hrs_lft_int <= hrs_lft_int + 1;
                                    end if;
                            else 
                                hrs_rght_int  <= hrs_rght_int + 1;
                            end if;
                        else 
                             min_lft_int <=  min_lft_int + 1;
                        end if;
                    else
                        min_rght_int <= min_rght_int + 1;
                    end if;
                else 
                    second_lft_int <= second_lft_int + 1;
                end if;
            else
                second_rght_int <= second_rght_int + 1;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
```

And that gives:

[image: master_tb.png]

In VHDL "+" for integer is defined as an operation on a type integer and not a modular integer, you have to check for the boundary condition yourself.

You might also notice I set the clk rate to 1 ps in simulation. A bit excessive but I wanted to search for roll over events.

A testbench can consist of as little as a direct entity instantiation with a single port association for the clk. (The waveforms are from the Device Under Test).

Comment: Thank you sir, @user1155120